# Galilean invariance/ scale invariance of KPZ

Tags: symmetry

I have problems with understanding what the Galilean invariance of [KPZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kardar%E2%80%93Parisi%E2%80%93Zhang_equation) 
means and how it is connencted to KPZ scale invariance?

How can I see that KPZ is scale invariant?

Why this symmetry impose that the MSR action depends only on the combinantion 
$\partial_t h- \lambda (\nabla h)^2$? (MSR action is an action from Martin-Siggia-Rose formalism, which depends on so called deterministic and noise variables)

And what is the Ward identity?

I am quite confused after the lecture I have heard...

---

Ward identity comes in my notes by claiming, that:

"For the full effective action S[h,p] (for the KPZ equation) we may introduce multiplicative renormalization

$\int dt dr p(Z\partial_t h - \lambda Z' (\nabla h)^2)$,

the symmetries implies $Z=Z'$ for all scales (Ward identity)."

Comment: You can't just throw abbreviations at us and expect us to know what you're talking about. What is the "MSR action"? Have you tried to just *do* a scale transform and see the equation is invariant? Why are you talking about "the Ward identity" when this is a general principle of quantum gauge theories, seemingly unrelated to the rest?

Comment: Sorry, it is only because I don't know how obvious it is for persons which know a lot about KPZ equation.

Comment: What do you mean with doing the scale transformation - setting x=bx, with some const b and then see if equation stays the same?

Comment: What lecture are you talking about? Who is the lecturer? Where is it given? Is it about KPZ equation of statistical physics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit fuzzy. I will do my best to answer and let you complain about what I did not understand properly. The references that I give are just papers that I know and like. There is much more to read on the topic.

I will use the following sign convention for $\lambda$,

$$ \partial_t h + \frac{\lambda}{2}\left(\vec{\nabla}h\right)^2 = \nu \nabla^2 h + \eta \, . \qquad (1) $$

I assume that you know what every term stands for. All the parameters are positive and $\eta(t,\vec{x})$ is a stochastic noise.

**Galilée invariance**: KPZ equation is invariant under Galilei transformations. If $h(t,\vec{x})$ is a solution of Eq. (1), then

$$\tilde{h}(t,\vec{x}) = h(t,\vec{x}-t \vec{u}) + \frac{1}{\lambda} \vec{u} \cdot \tilde{x} - \frac{u^2 t}{2 \lambda} \, , \qquad (2)$$

is a solution as well (with $\tilde{\eta}(t,\vec{x}) = \eta(t,\vec{x}-\vec{u}t)$). Note that the last term is quadratic in $\vec{u}$ and is usually not considered since only infinitesimally small values of $\vec{u}$ are needed for the Ward identities. Note that both sides of Eq. (1) are invariant under such a transformation independently. This implies that any function of (in particular) the left-hand-side will be a Galilei scalar.

This transformation is called Galilei invariance because Eq. (1) can be mapped onto Burgers equation,

$$ \partial_t \vec{v} + \left(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{\nabla}\right) \vec{v} = \nu \Delta \vec{v} + \vec{\nabla}\eta \, , \qquad (3)$$

with the definition, $\vec{v} = \lambda \vec{\nabla}h$. Burgers' equation is very similar to Navier-Stokes and describes some kind of hydrodynamic velocity field. The transformation (2) applied to $\vec{v}$ becomes

$$ \tilde{\vec{v}}(t,\vec{x}) = \vec{v}(t,\vec{x}-t\vec{u}) + \vec{u} \, .$$

It is a Galilei transformation.

**Scale invariance**: There is no easy was to see that Eq. (1) is scale invariant. It takes a lot of work to see it. This can be done using Renormalisation Group (RG) techniques (see e.g. [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.4650) and more references in it's bibliography) numerical simulations or even [experiments](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0105234v1). Note that the $d=1$ case has been solved analytically and the scale invariance of Eq. (1) proven mathematically. See e.g. [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.06185v1). Often it is simply just assumed that the stationary state is scale invariant.

In particular, scale invariance of the steady state implies that there are two scaling exponents ($\chi$ and $z$) and a scaling function $g(x)$ such that

$$ \langle \left[h(t+\tau,\vec{x}+\vec{r})-h(t,\vec{x}) \right]^2 \rangle = r^{2\chi} \, g\left(\frac{\tau}{r^z}\right) \, .$$

You can write similar expressions for all the correlation functions. Note that the steady state is invariant under space time translations as well as space rotations, $\left|\vec{r}\right| = r$.

For $d=1$, $\chi$ and $z$ are known. Huge amounts of work go into computing them for higher dimensions. Galilei invariance is a big help here because it relates one exponent to the other,

$$ \chi + z = 2 \, . \qquad (4)$$

Indeed, Galilei invariance insures (in particular) that $\lambda$ is not changed by the renormalisation group. Whatever the level of coarse graining, the two terms of the left-hand-side of Eq. (1) will always be related in the same way. If your system is scale invariant you can rescale space, time and field as

$$ x = \kappa \hat{x} \, , \quad t = \kappa^z \hat{t} \, , \quad h = \kappa^\chi \hat{h} \, .$$

Then the left-hand-side of Eq. (1) is rescaled as

$$ \kappa^{\chi-z} \partial_{\hat{t}} \hat{h} + \kappa^{2\chi-2} \left(\hat{\nabla}\hat{h}\right)^2 = \kappa^{\chi-z} \left[ \partial_{\hat{t}} \hat{h} + \kappa^{\chi+z-2} \left(\hat{\nabla}\hat{h}\right)^2 \right] \, .$$

The whole thing does not change (up to a prefactor that is absorbed into the renormalisation of $\nu$ and $\eta$) only if Eq. (4) is fulfilled.

**Advective non-linearity**: The left-hand-side of Eq. (1) should be considered as a block because in the hydrodynamic representation (Eq. (3)), it is the advective time derivative,

$$\frac{d \vec{v}(t,\vec{x}(t))}{d t} = \partial_t \vec{v} + \left(\vec{v}\cdot \vec{\nabla}\right) \vec{v} \, .$$

This shows as well why it is Galilei invariance that is responsible for the conservation (under RG transformations) of $\lambda$.

**Ward identities**: You can find the Ward identities as well as their derivation [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.2289).

Comment: Ok, I will start to analize the papers, thanks! I have one question: by the renormalization theory one often assumes that the scaling functions converge to some constant when the variable goes to infinity, g(x->\infty)->const. Why should this make sense?

Comment: There are two limits, $g(x\gg 1)$ and $g(x\ll 1)$. One is set to a constant simply as a definition of $\chi$, the other must be a power law. When $\tau= 0$, the correlation function should be a function of $r$ only, hence $g(x\ll 1) = cst$. On the other hand if $r\rightarrow 0$, only $\tau$ should remain, $g(x\gg 1)\sim x^{2\chi/z}$. Be careful about what correlation function you talk about. In the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kardar%E2%80%93Parisi%E2%80%93Zhang_equation) we have the opposite, when the system size is sent to infinity, $W(\infty,t)$ should only depend on $t$.